# How to store into DB RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq

I need to know how can i store `RadioButtonList` items into my SQL db, already have this for TextBoxes:

```
public class Botones
{
    public void SaveCVInfo2(string varOne,string varTwo, string  varThree)
{
    using (ConexionGeneralDataContext db = new ConexionGeneralDataContext())
    {
        Usuario_Web columna = new Usuario_Web();
        //Add new values to each fields
        columna.Nombre = varOne;
        columna.Apellido = varTwo;
        columna.Em_solicitado = varThree;
        //and the rest where the textboxes would have been


        //Insert the new Customer object
        db.Usuario_Web.InsertOnSubmit(columna);
        //Sumbit changes to the database
        db.SubmitChanges();
     }

}
}
```

Then reference them like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Botones botones = new Botones();
        botones.SaveCVInfo2(nombre.Text, Apellidos.Text, EmpleoS.Text);
    }
```

I need to know a way to add to the `columna` data from Radio Buttons in asp.net, while keeping this format of communication with the db.

BTW i have `varchar` tables for RadioButtonList data in my db.

I searched for some tutorials, but only found some old fashioned ADO connections examples, and i'm using Linq to SQL here.

This is a RadioButtonList I'm using in my `aspx` page:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList6" RepeatColumns = "2" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table"  runat="server">
<asp:ListItem ValidationGroup="Curriculum" style="margin-right:12px; margin-top:-10px" >Si</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem ValidationGroup="Curriculum" >No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you, i'll post my solution here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i solved it like this.

In my class:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Grupo_Zulcon
{
public partial class EnvianosTuCurriculum : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }




    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Botones botones = new Botones();
        botones.SaveCVInfo2(nombre.Text, Apellidos.Text, EmpleoS.Text, DireccionPersonal.Text, RadioButtonList6.SelectedItem.Text);
    }

}
}
```

And in aspx.cs codebehind file:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Botones botones = new Botones();
        botones.SaveCVInfo2(nombre.Text, Apellidos.Text, EmpleoS.Text, DireccionPersonal.Text, RadioButtonList6.SelectedItem.Text);
    }
```

For anyone who might need it, thx.